# Can't traverse from tail to head in doubly link list

Tags: c, data-structures, linked-list, doubly-linked-list

I've wrote the code for doubly link list in C, and it is traversing fine from head to tail but on traversing from tail (end) to head it gets stuck in an infinite loop and print only the data of the last node only and I can't figure out what's wrong.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct node {
    int data;
    struct node *prev;
    struct node *next;
};
typedef struct node list;

list *head, *current, *newn, *end;

int main() {
    int x, y;
    current = (list*)malloc(sizeof(list));
    printf("enter data:");
    scanf("%d", &current->data);

    current->next = NULL;
    current->prev = NULL;
    head = current;
    printf("do you want to enter more:");
    scanf("%d", &x);
    while (x == 1) {
        current->next = (list*)malloc(sizeof(list));
        printf("enter data:");
        scanf("%d", &current->next->data);
        current->next->prev = current->next;
        current->next->next = NULL;
        current = current->next;
        end = current;
        printf("do yo want to enter more:");
        scanf("%d", &x);
    }

    newn = head;
    while (newn != NULL) {
        printf("%d:%d:%d->", newn->prev, newn->data, newn->next);
        newn = newn->next;
    }
    while (end->prev != NULL) {
        printf("%d", end->data);
        end = end->prev;
    }
}
```

Comment: I removed tag [tag:c++]. The people in this community distinguish very strict between C and C++. Tag spamming is disliked and may result in down-votes...

Comment: `while(newn != NULL)` is different from `while(end->prev != NULL)`

Comment: `current->next->prev = current->next;` -> `current->next->prev = current;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Putting together answers from comments, here is the fixed code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
struct node
{
    int data;
    struct node *prev;
    struct node *next;
};
typedef struct node list;
list *head, *current, *newn, *end;

void exitWithFail() {
   printf("Error: exiting.\n");
   exit(1);
}

int main()
{
    int x,y,r;
    current = (list*)malloc(sizeof(list));
    printf("enter data:");
    r = scanf("%d",&current->data);
    if (r != 1) exitWithFail();
    current->next = NULL;
    current->prev = NULL;
    head = end = current;
    printf("do you want to enter more:");
    r = scanf("%d",&x);
    if (r != 1) exitWithFail();
    while(x == 1)
    {
        current->next = (list*)malloc(sizeof(list));
        printf("enter data:");
        r = scanf("%d",&current->next->data);
        if (r != 1) exitWithFail();
        current->next->prev = current; // problem No.1
        current->next->next = NULL;
        current = current->next;
        end = current;
        printf("do yo want to enter more:");
        r = scanf("%d",&x);
        if (r != 1) exitWithFail();    
    }
    newn = head;

    while(newn != NULL)
    {
        printf("%d ",newn->data);
        newn = newn->next;
    }
    printf("\n");
    while(end != NULL)     // Problem No. 2
    {
        printf("%d ",end->data);
        end = end->prev;
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: You should also change `head = current;` to `end  = head = current;` to allow for lists with a single node.

Comment: And always validate the return of `scanf` to prevent an endless loop if something other than a digit is entered, e.g. `if (scanf("%d",&current->next->data) != 1) { /* handle error or exit */ }`.

Comment: @chqrlie. Thanks, for the sake of completeness, both suggestions incorporated.